# Applying <h1> tags without affecting font family or font size

Tags: html

I want to put  tags around a some text without changing whatever font family and font size the text has already inherited.  I could redefine the CSS for h1 so that nothing is said about the font-family or font-size but then the values from the user agent would just come through. I need to define the CSS for h1 in a way that the user agent values are killed, something like

```
h1{
   font-family:none;
   font-size:none;
}
```

But I don't think that will work.

Thanks

Comment: Just specify same font-family and font-size as for normal text.

Comment: This is apparently (judging from the comments) based on a misunderstanding of how search engines work. If it were so easy to fool search engines, you would need to worry about more than just fonts when using `h1` for things that aren’t top-level headings (e.g., the way speech browsers handle heading elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [the inherit keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#inherit).

```
font-family: inherit;
font-size: inherit;
```

I can't think of a good reason for making the most important heading in your document indistinguishable from body text though. It runs the risk of being treated as a spam flag by search engines.

Comment: Search engines don't see font size. The only way they know something is important is by finding <h1> tags around it, which is precisely why I'm adding them. But I don't want to change the style that's already been applied to the text.

Comment: @Steve — Search engines are entirely capable of parsing CSS and JavaScript. Detecting the type of spam you are proposing is one of the reasons they developed that type of checking capability.

Comment: First, my information comes from "Learning Responsive Web Design," copyright 2014: "When a [search engine robot] looks at your website it only sees the HTML, not the design. It uses [the HTML] to determine how your page should appear in search results."   Second, what I'm doing is in no way spam.  The text is already large and bold, or whatever, it just doesn't have <h1> tags because it is was generated by a site builder.  I'm giving the user, here, a way to select the text and put <h1> tags around it, for the robots to find, without changing the style the user has already applied to the text.

Comment: Your information is wrong. Google [definitely pay attention to CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200510/google_seo_and_using_css_to_hide_text/) (that focuses on hiding of content, but 9 years later the technology will have advanced). Whenever you start changing markup in an effort to highlight things for search engines instead of people, you are heading closer to the "spam" side of the line.

Comment: "Whenever you start changing markup in an effort to highlight things for search engines instead of people, you are heading closer to the "spam" side of the line" - Agreed.  But I'm not doing that. Web designers insert h1 tags to show what's important and Google reads them to find what's important. My users are non-technical and can't insert HTML tags manually.  Instead they select the line and hit this button that inserts h1 tags for them, programatically. No one's trying to slip spam passed Google.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `inherit`, this will work, which will inherit your parent style

```
font-family: inherit
```

Answer (score -1):

Font size is simple:

```
h1 { font-size: 100%; }
```

Font family is trickier, and the most robust way is to declare the font family `h1` and its parent together. Assuming that `h1` is a child of `body`, you could use

```
body, h1 { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

These settings, like any settings you might set, are ineffective against user style sheet rules that override them, as well as against browser defaults when the browser has been configured to ignore font sizes and/or families specified on web pages.

However, they work wider than the use of `inherit`, which is not recognized by some old browsers.

Comment: @Steve, care to spell that out? Whet exactly is incorrect in my answer?